# Xamarin.Forms EntryCell SetFocus

Tags: focus, xamarin.forms

Xamarin.Forms

Set Focus on EntryCell in TableView

How do I ...

```
EntryCell.Focus();
```

As that doesn't exist... I've seen a post about possibly doing

```
EntryCell.Keyboard = null;
```

Is that correct, or is there something better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue I found was that the underlying field in the cell that actually needs to get the focus is not available in the EntryCell class. I implemented this functionality by customising the layout using an EntryCellRenderer, and a dirty hack that relies on a specific order of the subview hierarchy. This example is for iOS. You will need to redo this for each of the platforms you need to support.

**Define a specific subclass for the EntryCell**

```
public class FocusableEntryCell: EntryCell
{
    public bool ShouldGetFocus = false;
    public FocusableEntryCell ()
    {
    }
}
```

**Create your renderer and export it**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (FocusableEntryCell), typeof (FocusableEntryCellRenderer))]

public class FocusableEntryCellRenderer: EntryCellRenderer
{
    public override UITableViewCell GetCell (Cell item, UITableViewCell reusableCell, UITableView tv)
    {
        var cell = base.GetCell (item, reusableCell, tv);
        var castCell = (FocusableEntryCell)item;
        // Bit of a hack below, but EntryCellRenderer.EntryCellTableViewCell is a private class so 
        // we can't access the TextField via a defined accessor - we have to know the subview hierarchy
        UITextField textField = (UITextField)cell.ContentView.Subviews [0];
        if (castCell.ShouldGetFocus) {
            textField.BecomeFirstResponder ();
        }
        return cell;
    }
}
```

**When creating your cell, set the focus on the one you want to get focus**

```
var cell = new FocusableEntryCell {
    Label = "My cell",
    ShouldGetFocus = true
};
```

Comment: You can also check out the Android [XLabs' ExtendedEntryCellRenderer](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Forms/XLabs.Forms.Droid/Controls/ExtendedEntryCell/ExtendedEntryCellRenderer.cs) for an example of how to at least setup the renderer on Android (it does not actually include the code to `Focus` an `EntryCell`).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to create a custom ViewCell that contains a Label and an Entry like so

```
public class MyCustomEntryCell : ViewCell
{
    public Label Label
    {
        get;
        set; 
    }

    public Entry Entry
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public MyCustomEntryCell
    {
         Label = new Label(); 
         Entry = new Entry(); 
         View = new StackLayout
         {
             Children =
             {
                 Label,
                 Entry  
             }
         }
    }

}`
```

Then instead of calling EntryCell.Focus(), call MyCustomEntryCell.Entry.Focus()